# Meaning of "id" in yesod persistent field attributes

Tags: yesod

What is the meaning of "id=name" in the definition of the User entity?
Any resources about the persist field attributes?

User
    name Text Asc id=name

Answer (score 0):

The id=... attribute sets the column name for the tables primary key.

For Example:

```
Product id=product_id
    name Text
    quantityInStock Int
```

... will create a table with an integer primary key called "product_id"